# How to copy selected row in List View to clipboard in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to copy the selected row all sub items, i am using below code. But its copying only first column of the row only.

Clipboard.SetText(lv.Items.Item(0).Text)

Also it is possible to copy the complete row and paste in excel as grid?

Comment: It's only copying the first column of the first row because that's exactly what you're telling it to copy. This issue has nothing to do with copying to the Clipboard. This is an issue wholly and solely about getting data from a `ListView`, so you nneed to put some thought and effort into that problem.

Comment: Firstly, you say that you to copy from the selected row but your code just gets the first row, with no consideration of what's selected. Have you made any effort to find out how to get the selected rows from a `ListView`? It would appear not. The very first thing you should have done was look at [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview?view=netframework-4.8) to see what members it has and which one(s) provide access to the user's selection.

Comment: Once you have the correct item, you then need to put some thought and effort into getting all the data out of it. Again, read the relevant documentation and look for examples online. It's hard to believe that you wouldn't find any relevant information if you tried.

Comment: I am using below code
Clipboard.SetText(lv.SelectedItems(0).Text)

It's copying the selected row of first Colum. BUt i need copy all the columns.

Comment: Is the second part of your question regarding the pasting in Excel, actual end goal of what you're asking about here?  I ask because there are quite a few ways to get data from a DVG (Although I would even question that) to Excel that are much more economical and robust than using the clipboard

Comment: Yes i want to copy the selected row from listview with all sub items and need to paste in excel.

Comment: Try something like: `Clipboard.SetText(String.Join(ControlChars.Tab, lv.SelectedItems(0).SubItems.Cast(Of ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem).Select(Function(x) x.Text)))`. Make sure to select an item before calling that.